# How to filter an array with another array in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I am basically trying to say "give me all added items that were not actually added to the cart" with my filter function below. If any of the addedItems product ids cannot be found in the cartItems ids then it should return those items.  But instead unaddedCartItems is an empty array when I know there are addedItems ids that are not the same as any of the cartItems ids.  Do anyone know how to achieve this?

```
const unaddedCartItems = addedItems.filter((addedItem) => {
    cartItems.forEach((cartItem) => {
        return cartItem.id !== addedItem.productId;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `return` is nested under `forEach` and you aren't returning that value in your `filter`. Instead, use `find`:

```
const unaddedCartItems = addedItems.filter( addedItem => {
    return !cartItems.find( cartItem => cartItem.id === addedItem.productId );
});
```

`find` loops through an array until it finds a matching item. This means that if it finds the id in `cartItems`, it will immediately stop the loop and return the item.

Comment: Function `find` to accomplish that requirement? What about the function `some`?

Comment: Although will work, the best approach is using the function `some`.

Answer (score 2):

Would using `some` work here?

```
const unaddedCartItems = addedItems.filter((addedItem) => 
    !cartItems.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === addedItem.productId);
```

Comment: You still need to `return` the result from `.some`

Comment: This is also less performant than `find` when you have a lot of items in your cart. If the item doesn't exist in the cart, this code will loop through **every** cartItem instead of stopping once it finds a match.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda That's incorrect, [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) tells you whether a single element matches it, so it will also stop after it finds it, and is the better one to use because in `find`, you are wasting its return value since we only need a boolean.

Comment: Right, they both work the same, but how they are using it here is missing out on the performance of using `.some` or `.find`.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda the way was implemented that arrow function doesn't need a return statement.

Comment: @Ele right, they updated the answer after my comment.

Answer (score 0):

because your return is nested under forEach and you aren't returning that value in your filter

Comment: So how should OP fix it? They want to know a solution to their problem, not just why it's not working.